# Git Can I make separate change to the same file on different branches

Tags: git

Scenario:  I am working on a file: foo.html.  I've made a lot of important changes, but not ready to commit and push live.  A customer comes in a says, "Hey, we need an urgent text change to foo.html".  Normally, I create a copy of foo.html (foo-copy.html) not in git, Undo all my changes to foo.html and make the new urgent change. After committing the urgent fix, I then copy my changes stored in foo-copy.html back into foo.html.  pwhew!

Is there an easier way to do this in Git?  Like stash current state of foo.html in one branch so the current changes are not seen in my workspace, open another branch to make urgent changes to foo.html, commit and then pop the stashed file back in the first branch?

Hopefully this makes sense.  And thanks for any tips.

Comment: Can you do this just by switching between branches?

Comment: If the important changes have been committed on their own branch, then yes: OP can just checkout master and write his hotfix without affecting the important changes

Answer (score 2):

If your Git version is at least 2.6 (the feature went in at 2.5 but there were some fairly major bug fixes immediately, and then minor ones since 2.6), I recommend using the Git Worktree feature, with `git worktree add`:

```
$ git clone ... somerepo
$ cd somerepo
$ git checkout -b newfeature develop
... hack away for a while ...
```

At this point you get an interruption.  Rather than trying to save everything away, or making a new clone (which also works), you can now do this:

```
$ git worktree add -b quickfix ../temptree master
```

Now you have, in `../temptree` (next to `somerepo`), a second work-tree in a new branch `quickfix` that branches from `master`.  Your existing work-tree, the one you are in right now, is totally undisturbed and remains on your branch `newfeature`.

You can do whatever work you like in the new directory.  It has its own HEAD and its own index.  The special constraint is that it cannot be on the *same* branch as your "main" repository, nor can your main repository switch to its branch (all added worktrees must be on their own separate branches).

When you are done with an added work-tree, just remove it.

Comment: And maybe `quickfix` should eventually be merged into (or rebased onto) `master`.

Comment: @torek couldn't he simply stash his current changes, checkout new branch, do the changes, go back to the first branch and pop the changes?

Comment: @MateuszChrzaszcz: sure - but the nice thing about added work-trees is that you get a completely separate playground, as it were, so that you don't have to worry about untracked files, ignored files, and so on. This is much more generally useful than stashes.